# Using IsNumeric to delete rows of data

Tags: excel, vba, isnumeric

I have two columns of data I am cleaning up using VBA.  If the value in column A is non-numeric or blank, I need to delete the entire row.  Below is a sample of the data and the code I am trying to use.  It seems to be completely skipping over the portion of the code that deletes the rows if IsNumeric returns false.

```
9669    DONE
9670    OPEN
Order # STATUS

9552    
9672
```

Code that isn't working.

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & max_col)
    If IsNumeric(cell) = False Then
        Cells(cell, 1).Select
        Rows(cell).EntireRow.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use just

```
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
```

or, if you don't know for sure whether there will be empty or not numeric cells

```
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
        If WorksheetFunction.Count(.Cells) < .Rows.Count Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop from the bottom

```
Dim max_col as long
max_col = 100
Dim i as Long
For i = max_col to 1 step -1
   If Not isnumeric(activesheet.cells(i,1)) then
       activesheet.rows(i).delete
   End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

When deleting (or adding, for that matter) rows you need to loop backwards through the data set - See @ScottCraner's example for an exact answer like that - or, you create the range of cells to delete then delete at once, like below:

```
Dim rowNo as Long

For rowNo = 1 to max_col

    Dim cell as Range
    Set cell = Range(rowNo,1) 

    If IsNumeric(cell) Then

        Dim collectRows as Range
        If collectRows is Nothing Then
            Set collectRows = cell
        Else
            Set collectRows = Union(collectRows,cell)
        End If

    End If

Next

collectRows.EntireRow.Delete
```